# Keep correct scene scale using Blender VR Scene Inspection

Tags: vr, oculus

I have tried using a Quest 2 and OpenXR addon "VR Scene Inspection" for Blender, and it works really well, it is fantastic to navigate the same 3D scene in VR.

One feature I found hard to put is the scale of the view. It is possible to (too) easily change the distance between eyes, the height of the view, thus making it impossible to have correct vision of an architecture scene (you can easily get the field of view of a child or a giant).

Are there any options to keep the height always correct (My workaround is to lower in Z my entire scene 1.9 m below the (0,0,0) blender)
And keep correct scale (I didn't find any options right for that)

Comment: Are those options of the addon you are talking about or Blender settings?

Comment: I think it should be in the OpenXR support with the addon that those option should be. Blender already have unit system.

Comment: So this question isn't really asking about a problem with Blender, more about the addon and should be addressed to the developers there?

Comment: It is an interesting question, as most part of blender like the cycles renderer are in add-on form, what should or shouldn't be addressed as add-on support, or as blender supported features (usual bug report) ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry - I confused this with an external add-on. "Official" add-ons are supposedly Blender features... Hopefully someone can answer your question. Or maybe this might work better in the future, since at the moment the add-on shows a warning: "This is an early, limited preview of in development VR support for Blender."